# Log supermodularity property of Bivariate Normal CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

I am trying to understand for bivariate normal variables, when their correlation increases, can we show in certian sense the distribution is concentrated on the 45 degree line.

For example, let $F(X,Y,\rho)$ be the CDF of a bivariate normal distribution with mean $0$ and covariance matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1, \rho\\\rho,1\end{pmatrix}$. For $\rho\geq 0$ and $x\leq y$, can we show
$$\frac{\partial^2 \log F(x,y,\rho)}{\partial x \, \partial \rho}\geq 0 \quad ?$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you, I have revised the question.